# Single Theme folder for Multiple Wordpress

Tags: theme-development, themes

I ran into a scenario where I want to achieve this.

WordPress Site 1
WordPress Site 2
WordPress Site 3
WordPress Site 4

I want theses four sites to have a single theme folder and it get themes and run themes from there not from

WpSite1/wp-content/themes
WpSite2/wp-content/themes
and so on

Thanks

Comment: Setup multisite

Comment: you *could* set up a server cron job to copy a master theme directory to all the subdirectories on a regular basis...

Comment: This is a good case for multisite imo. Is there a specific reason you want to do this?

Comment: Hi, guys I am aware of multisite. But the scenario is I am going to have 250 sites per month and will have 10, 000 per year these are marketing sites using 1 or 2 themes.

Answer (score 1):

WP inherently supports multiple theme directories via `register_theme_directory()`.

However since it requires web–accessible directory you might have to symlink or otherwise muck with it server–side so that all sites pick it up. Up to your configuration how to do it exactly.

Comment: Will i work if we have multiple server using the same theme and we want those server with multiple wordpress installation to look for themes in a single place.

Comment: I kind doubt you will be able to reliably and securely organize such place _across servers_ without syncing.